# How to align a rotated text to left in multirow cell?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rotating, cell

I am working on `Springer` template, I created a `tabularx` `table` which contains rotated multirow cells. this is the table which I create it:
[image]

I want to align all the rotated `columnrow` to left, and the Text which in the last cell in the middle. like that:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
    

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{pdflscape}



\usepackage{xtab}

\usepackage{pdflscape}





    \start{document}
    \begin{landscape}
 
    \begin{table} [htp]
    
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \makegapedcells
    %0.0255
    %0.0745
    %0.0145
    
    \begin{tabularx} {\linewidth}{ | wc{0.012\textwidth}  wc{0.060\textwidth}
                                     *{32}{|wc{0.011\textwidth}}
                                     % *{9}{|wc{0.011\textwidth}}
                                    % *{5}{|wc{0.011\textwidth}}
                                    |X|}  
    
    
    
    \hline  
      \multicolumn{2}  {|wc{0.072\textwidth}|}   { \multirow{2}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{ Text}} }
      & \multicolumn{18}  {wc{0.198\textwidth}|}   {Text Text} 
      & \multicolumn{9}  {wc{0.099\textwidth}|}   {Text}
      & \multicolumn{5}  {c|}   {Text Text}
      & \multirow{2}{=}{{ Text }} 
    
    \\
    \cline{3-34}                
                                                %19&20&21&22&23&24&25&
    &&
     { \multirow{11}{*}{\rotatebox{90} {TextTextText}} }&
    { \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90} { {Text Text}} } } &
    { \multirow{11}{*}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text Text}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text Text}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text Text Text}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextTextText}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText }} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text Text }} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    { \multirow{11}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text TextText}} }&
     \multicolumn{7}  {c|}   {Cellular} 
                                                                        % 26&27
                                 &\multicolumn{2}  {c|}   {Text}                & { \multirow{3}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
    { \multirow{3}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextTextText}} }&
    { \multirow{3}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
    { \multirow{3}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
    { \multirow{3}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text TextText}} }&
    
    \\
    \cline{21-29}
    % &&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27& 28&29&30&31&32&
    
    && & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &
    \multicolumn{3} {c|}   {Text} & 
    \multicolumn{2} {c|}   {Text} & 
    Text& 
    Text &
    { \multirow{2}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    { \multirow{2}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    %%T class
      & & & & &
    
    
    
    \\
     \cline{21-26}
    && & & & & & & & & &  & & & & & & & & & 
    { \multirow{2}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Te}} }&
    { \multirow{2}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    { \multirow{2}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} }&
    { \multirow{2}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} } &
    { \multirow{2}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} } &
    { \multirow{2}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}} } & &
    
     & &  & & & & &
    % && & & & & & & & & &  & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  & & & & &
    
    \\
    
    && & & & & & & & & &  & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  & & & & &
    \\
    
    && & 
    & & & & & & & &  & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  & & & & &
    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is not compilable. Where does `\startdocument` come from, for instance?